# Creating UI element won't let change position

Tags: xcode, swift

I tried this:

```
@IBAction func test(sender : AnyObject){
    let height:CGFloat = 44
    var tableFrame:CGRect = tableView.frame;
    var fieldFrame = CGRect()
    fieldFrame.origin = tableFrame.origin
    fieldFrame.size.height = height
    fieldFrame.size.width = tableFrame.size.width
    var textField = UITextField(frame: fieldFrame)
    textField.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 1)
    view.addSubview(textField)
    tableFrame.size.height = tableFrame.size.height - height
    tableFrame.origin.y = tableFrame.origin.y + height
    tableView.frame = tableFrame
}
```

When running, black field appears, but table won't move nor change size. Removing line

```
view.addSubview(textField)
```

allows table to change size and move, but, obviously, no field appears. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

your textfield is actually on top of tableview. Your touch actions are probably going to the text fieldview and not to the tableview

Comment: Sorry, what touch actions? I meant, table won't change its position as it should `tableFrame.origin.y = tableFrame.origin.y + height`

Comment: Sorry, when you said you couldn't move the table, I thought you were talking about the scrolling for tableview. Did you try adding textField after you resize the tableview?

Comment: I just tried running your code and it is changing the size of the tableview. Try adding border color to the frame and you should be able to see where it is moving. Couple of things I did to verify is to change the height to something like 100 for tableview and y origin shifted by 100 from top so I could see the borders that were getting hidden because of navigation bar